# How to add 30 days in a timestamp in jstl

Tags: jsp, jstl

I need to add 30 days to the current system date in timestamp. How can I acheive that? I am having below code:

```
<%

    Date date= new Date();
    long time = date.getTime();
    Timestamp ts = new Timestamp(time);
     %> 
    <c:set var="currentDate"><%=ts%></c:set>
    <c:if test="${startDate lt currentDate}">
        <c:if test="${endDate gt currentDate}">
```

How can I make ts+ 30? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use calendar:

```
Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 30);
Date d=cal.getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> 
<%
 Date date= new Date();
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime (date);
 cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 30);
 date = cal.getTime ();
%>
<c:set var="currentDate"><%=date%></c:set>
<c:out value="currentDate"/>
```