# How to indicate the date is within 60 days in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a table to show the service name and the service date

I wirte this code and it works fine:

```
<display:table name="${serviceList}" class="its" uid="row"
        sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="serviceMaint_view" export="false" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="descending" id="serviceTable">
    <display:column style="width: 30%" title="Service Name" property="serviceName"  />

    <display:column style="width: 10%" title="Service Date" property="serviceDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" />
</display:table>
```

I make another column to indicate the service date is within 60 days, for example,  if the service date is within 60 days, the column will show "Service in use" whereas if the service date is more than 60 days, there will be no indicator in the column (leave the column empty).

I have read this post [How to add 30 days in a timestamp in jstl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28374791/how-to-add-30-days-in-a-timestamp-in-jstl) . I apply the solution in `<display:column>`, however it does not work (will show the code below). I think maybe some taglib are missing so I add them in the code but it still not work.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.*,common.utility.*"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>
<%@page import="java.text.DateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Calendar" %> 
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix = "fmt" %>

<display:table name="${serviceList}" class="its" uid="row"
        sort="list" pagesize="10" requestURI="serviceMaint_view" export="false" defaultsort="2" defaultorder="descending" id="serviceTable">
    <display:column style="width: 30%" title="Service Name" property="serviceName"  />

    <display:column style="width: 10%" title="Service Date" property="serviceDate" format="{0,date,dd-MM-yyyy}" />

<display:column>
   <%
   Date date= serviceDate; //serviceDate cannot be resolved to a variable
   Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
   cal.setTime (date);
   cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 60);
   date = cal.getTime (); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date
   %>
   <c:if test="${serviceDate ge date}">
    <c:out value = "Service in use" />
   </c:if>   

</display:column>       

<!--also try to use <s:if> but still get error -->

 <display:column>
 <%
 Date date= serviceDate; //serviceDate cannot be resolved to a variable
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.setTime (date);
 cal.add (Calendar.DATE, 60);
 date = cal.getTime (); //Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date 
 to java.sql.Date
 %>
  <s:if tests='%{#serviceDate ge date}'>
  Service in use
  </s:if> 


</display:column>

</display:table>
```

I see a post mentions to put in the controller to do it. (sorry I forget which post) If in the controller, does it means the indicator needs to store in the database? If store in the database, I think the record will become static and cannot be changed unless I modify it in the database, so how does the program "knows" the service date is or is not within 60 days?

I have no idea how to indicate the date is within 60 days in `<display:column>`?
Do you have idea about it? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(Please note I have an idea and this may not be a good solution but it suits my case so I follow the idea to solve the problem and I would like to post here as an answer).

Firstly, get the service date by variable.

Next, add 60 days to the service date and make it as a variable.

Then, do the calculation to find out the day to determine whether the service date is within 60 days or not.